# Value won't push to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below, I assign a value to a variable from JSON with this `var tag = data[j]['text'];` and I output it with this `console.log(tag);` (for testing) which works.

I try to push the values into an array with `tags.push(tag);` but it WILL NOT WORK!

Why won't these values go into the array?  I am just trying to get the contents of `tag` into an array...

```
function GetAvailableTags() {
            var url = '/TextCodes/TextCodes?key=';
            var tagGroups = [];
            $('.ui-autocomplete-input').each(function () {
                var key = $(this).attr('id');
                var tags = [];
                //console.log(key);
                $.getJSON(url + key, function (data) {
                    for (var j = 0, len = data.length; j < len; j++) {
                        var tag = data[j]['text'];
                        console.log(tag);
                        tags.push(tag);
                    }
                });
                console.log(tags.length);
                for (var k = 0, len = tags.length; k < len; k++) {
                    console.log(tags[k]);
                }
            });
        }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You must defer using the response from the JSON call until the call has actually completed; the JavaScript program doesn't wait for the response. Use Deferreds or the success handler, and put your code in there instead. See http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: Ah not the scope sorry, missed a bracket...

Comment: You are logging the array before the ajax response fills it. See [How to return the response from an AJAX call from a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call-from-a-function)

Comment: Am I not simply doing what is being done successfully here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5273921/1477388 ?  Why won't it work for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is kind of long and stupid, but it works.  Now, I can access the variables like an array `textCodes['taxes']`.  sdespont's `async` note helped, too.

```
    var textCodes = GenerateTextCodes();
    console.log(textCodes);

    function GenerateTextCodes() {
        var arr = [];
        $('.ui-autocomplete-input').each(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            arr[id] = GetAvailableTags(id);
        });
        //console.log(arr['taxes']);
        return arr;
    }

    // get all autocomplete element IDs and put them into an array
    function GetAvailableTags(key) {
        var url = '/TextCodes/TextCodes?key=';
        var tags = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: url + key,
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //console.log(data[0].text);
                //console.log(data.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    //console.log(data[i].text);
                    tags.push(data[i].text);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('an error occurred!');
            }
        });
        //console.log(tags);
        return tags;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous function. It means that your code

```
console.log(tags.length);
for (var k = 0, len = tags.length; k < len; k++) {
    console.log(tags[k]);
}
```

will be executed before the `$.getJSON` callback function :

```
function () {
    var key = $(this).attr('id');
    var tags = [];
    //console.log(key);
    $.getJSON(url + key, function (data) {
        for (var j = 0, len = data.length; j < len; j++) {
            var tag = data[j]['text'];
            console.log(tag);
            tags.push(tag);
        }
    }
```

It is why your variable seems to be empty when look into in your code above, but how it is possible that the data are printed with `console.log(tag);` in the callback function.

**Update**

Here is an example of using $.ajax method instead of $.getJSON to specify that the data must be retrieved synchronously using the parameter `asynch : false`

By that way, the server call response (success callback) is mandatory to continue the process. The disadvantage of this non-standard way is that your web page could be freezed waiting the server response. It is not the best elegant way to do that, but sometimes it is useful.

```
function GetAvailableTags() {
    var url = '/TextCodes/TextCodes?key=';
    var tagGroups = [];
    $('.ui-autocomplete-input').each(function () {
        var key = $(this).attr('id');
        var tags = [];
        //console.log(key);
        $.ajax({
            url: url + key,
            type: 'POST',
            asynch: false,//specify to stop JS execution waiting the server response
            success: function (data) {
                for (var j = 0, len = data.length; j < len; j++) {
                    var tag = data[j]['text'];
                    console.log(tag);
                    tags.push(tag);
                }
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('an error occurred!');
            }
        });
        console.log(tags.length);
        for (var k = 0, len = tags.length; k < len; k++) {
            console.log(tags[k]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How, then, can I get the json data into an array?

Comment: You are pushing the value into the array. You are just tryin to display it before it gets there. You may consider using $.ajax and setting async=false rather than the getJSON shorthand: see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Your data are in the array, but only when the callback has been executed. Add your logic into the callback to use the array data like form element value updating or whatever you want to do. You could also call a function to execute at then end of the callback.

Comment: Where is the callback function for the `$.getJSON` method?  On http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ they just seem to be doing what I am doing, basically.  They loop through with `$.each` and push to array...

Comment: The callback is the function defined as second parameter of the $.getJSON method. This function is called when the server replies the data. You are already using the callback, it is where you are creating the array

Comment: Thank you for the update, but when I run `console.log(tags[k]);` it outputs `0` (zero).  It seems I am at the same place I was before.  `console.log(tag);` works fine, just as before, but when the data is added to the array, it won't seem to be read...  Here is the actual datasource I am using http://tinyurl.com/cmpf7d9 (ex. /TextCodes/TextCodes?key=taxes).  The keys I am passing are `#propertyInfo, #legalDesc, #taxes, #additionalTaxes, #mortgagesLiensCourt, #additionalMatters`